# Values for a fixed header

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to know, that if I want to keep a `<header>` fixed, what values should images inside that header and the items below it carry? Here I am trying to create a shrinkable fixed header but the images don't adjust to the size of the header and remain the same when the header shrinks. I have tried keeping the overflow value to visible as well as hidden and it is not working. The content below the header also overwrites it and ends up becoming over the header. What sort of values should I be using here, and how can I make it easier for myself the next time?

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lf7ys6v4/2/

Here's what I have tried so far.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lf7ys6v4/16/

The header is reducing in size as I had wanted, and the fixed menu is not getting skewed up. One of the major problems I have is though, the logo and the image on the right along with the text are not decreasing in size as the header does. There are some issues with the menu as well (the gap that remains between it and the header when the header decreases in size).

(I had added the wrong fiddle. The right fiddle has been updated)

Comment: Maybe the question is clear for other, but I don't understand what you exactly want, but I want to help you, so help me a little bit. So what I understand is when someone scrolls, the height of the Header should go to 100px (this is working), but the content below it, should be visible right? Did you want more or is that everything?

Comment: I want the menu to be fixed as well. The height of the header does go to 100px, but the images don't adjust accordingly. And the content should start after the header, and the menu should be below the header, but both things are not working.

Comment: @user3409468 you need something like:  http://jsfiddle.net/Lf7ys6v4/6/ ?

Comment: Ok, first let us clear the fixed thing. To make both fixed, both the menu and the header has to be fixed, also you should use a z-index if they are at the same place. (like menu is over the header). You are using height `auto` which can lead to wrong values, maybe you should consider `px` or `%` values, This should help you get the height right. To make the content under the fixed area, you have to wrap the content and do a margin-top til the right position. Like `margin-top: 100px` or if you want some extra same `margin-top: 120px` or `margin-top: 125px`. You also can use position and top

Comment: ketan, that is exactly what I want. Only you will size that the size of the header is not adjusting. Can you try one fiddle with the header size reduced to 50 px and the image size adjusting accordingly with it?

Comment: @user3409468 I don't understand what you are saying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set header and menu `position:fixed;` and set top position of header, menu and content:

```
$("#cssmenu").css('top',$('header').height());
$('.content').css("top",($('header').height() + $("#cssmenu").height())) ;.
```

**CSS:**

```
.content{
    position:relative;
}

#cssmenu {
    position: fixed;
}
```

Check [Fiddle Here.](http://jsfiddle.net/Lf7ys6v4/6/)